# What is the proper use of the tags <q>, <abbr>, <defn>, <ins>, <del>, and <s>?

Tags: html, semantics, markup

There are some semantic markup tags that I rarely ever see used.

For instance,

`<q>`, `<abbr>`, `<defn>`, `<ins>`, `<del>`, and `<s>`.

Should such tags be used, and if so, in what context?

Comment: This site might be of help to you http://html5doctor.com/

Comment: You can find all the information here:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: This question is probably gonna get closed as too broad. Mozilla has some good docs. ex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr

Comment: There is no need to remove the HTML5 tag from this as the semantic means of some tags has changed between HTML4 and HTML5. For example: `<s>`.

Comment: **Mozilla Docs sux**, why do you think people come to [*SO*](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`<q>` tag**

The HTML `<q>` tag is used for indicating short quotations (i.e. quotations that needs to display within a non-quoted paragraph).  for long quotations use [blockquote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) element.

**[Sample Code](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_q_tag.cfm)** - [q](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q)

---

**`<abbr>` tag**

The HTML `<abbr>` tag is used for indicating an abbreviation.

**[Sample Code](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_abbr_tag.cfm)**  - [abbr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn)

---

**`<dfn>` tag**

The HTML `<dfn>` tag is used for indicating a definition. The  tag surrounds the word/term being defined.

**[Sample Code](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_dfn_tag.cfm)** - [dfn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn)

---

**`<ins>` tag**

The HTML `<ins>` tag is used for markup of inserted text.

**[Sample Code](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_ins_tag.cfm)** - [ins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ins)

---

**`<del>` tag**

The HTML `<del>` tag is used for markup of deleted text.

**[Sample Code](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_del_tag.cfm)** - [del](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/del)

---

**`<s>` tag**

The HTML `<s>` tag is used for indicating text that is no longer accurate or no longer relevant. For example, it could be used to demonstrate a product that has had its price marked down, whilst still displaying the original price but with a line through the middle.

**[Sample Code](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_s_tag.cfm)** - [s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s)

Comment: great answer! much better than cnp!

Comment: Why downvotes??? an explanation would be better..!

Comment: PRobably down voted by the guy who answered before you but only cnp'd his answer. Not a real good answer. I mean if you're just gonna cnp, you might as well just put "Use Google" as your answer. lol. Don't worry bout the downvote, GREAT ANSWER HERE!

Answer (score 0):

[From the HTML Documentation on elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/elements.html):

- The [`q`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/q.html#q) element represents phrasing content quoted from another source.
- The [`abbr`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/abbr.html#abbr) element represents an abbreviation or acronym.
- The [`dfn`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/dfn.html#dfn) element represents the defining instance of a term.
- The [`ins`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/ins.html#ins) element represents a range of text that has been inserted (added) to a document.
- The [`del`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/del.html#del) element represents a range of text that has been deleted from a document.
- The [`s`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/s.html#s) element represents contents that are no longer accurate or no longer relevant and that therefore has been “struck” from the document.